# do file.do command in bash script

Tags: bash

I want to automate opening simulation files in ModelSim. Modelsim uses .do files from which you pass instructions. To be able to automate, I need for cycle and bash seemed to me like a proper choice.

But .do files are called with ***do anything.do*** command. Sadly, bash sees do as a part of other function (like for cycle) and I don't know, **how to instruct bash, that a line is a command** I want to pass into the shell.

Is it even possible? Or is there a better way to do it?

Example of bash file:

```
#!/bin/bash    
printf "Solution 1 will be opened.\n"
cd solution_1/intel_cosim.prj/verification
do ../../../sol_vsim.do mi32_to_mi_inst 1
cd ../../../
```

Example of .do file

```
OpenFile vsim.wlf
add wave -divider solution_1
add wave -radix decimal -group all_1 /tb/mi32_to_mi_inst/*
add wave -radix decimal -color orange -in -group inputs_1 /tb/mi32_to_mi_inst/*
add wave -radix decimal -color red -out -group outputs_1 /tb/mi32_to_mi_inst/*
wave zoom range 12ns 250ns
echo --------- solution_1 has been opened ---------
```

Comment: Add full path to your `do` command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `do` is in a directory that is in $PATH variable, then you can use `command do`.

Answer (score 1):

Precede `d` (or `o`, doesn't matter) with a backslash.

```
\do anything.do
```

Answer (score 0):

in bash environment ,"vsim -do name.do" works

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34868708)

Comment: Please indicate why do you think this is the solution.